# Adding fields to a class via setattr vs. storing a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a class called User:

```
class User(object):

    def __init__(self, arg1, ..., traits = None):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        ...
        self.traits = traits
```

User has a property `traits` which is a dictionary. It's intended to be a catch-all that I can populate when I need to hold a bit more information about a user other than basic stuff like email address, userID, etc.

Would it be any more or less efficient to create a `Traits` class, and set the properties in it's `__init__` with `setattr`? Would lookups work any better? Is there anything that this machinery would buy me, or is it just more work in the end?

Comment: re: `traits = {}` -- that's probably a bad idea.  All `User` instances which don't have a `traits` dictionary passed will share the same instance.  (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for a fuller explanation.)

Comment: Nice...+1 for you. So `traits = None`, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me, I would be tempted to re-write as:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, **traits):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.traits = traits
```

If you really wanted, you could then override to fall back on the traits dictionary if an attribute can't be found:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self.traits[name]
```

Example:

```
>>> u = User(1, 2, email='something')
>>> y = User(1, 2, email='bob', telno='999')
>>> u.arg1, u.arg2, u.email
(1, 2, 'something')
>>> y.arg1, y.arg2, y.email, y.telno
(1, 2, 'bob', '999')
>>> y.arg1, y.arg2, y.email, y.something
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#105>", line 1, in <module>
    y.arg1, y.arg2, y.email, y.something
  File "/home/jon/adfafasdf.py", line 7, in __getattr__
    return self.traits[name]
KeyError: 'something'
```

So you may wish to make that a more sensible error, and change to:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        return self.traits[name]
    except KeyError as e:
        raise AttributeError() # with suitably formatted string
```

Comment: Would you expect this to give any advantage memory-/readability-/performance-wise?

Comment: @BenDundee -- It's probably worse performance-wise, but it gives a slightly different API. `user.traits.whatever` becomes `user.whatever`.  It gets a little interesting when you try to set attributes however ... You could get differences between `user.whatever` and `user.traits["whatever"]` depending on how you set attributes.  Memory wise, It's probably slightly better too (classes take more memory than a dict), but really not a whole lot better.

Comment: @mgilson Yup - I'm going from the view point that the basic stuff looks like it's attributes of the object, so keep traits as a dict, and fallback on unknown attributes and assume it's a possible trait. But yeah... we've come at the problem from two different ways - which is always a good thing! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the instance's `__dict__` directly (assuming that it doesn't implement `__slots__` or anything silly like that)

Here's a simple example:

```
class Traits(object):
    pass

class User(object):
    def __init__(self,**traits):
        self.traits = Traits()
        self.traits.__dict__.update(traits)

a = User(eye_color="blue")
print a.traits.eye_color
```

Of course, it is probaby *safer* (but slightly less efficient) to just do:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self,**traits):
        self.traits = Traits()
        for k,v in traits.items():
            setattr(traits,k,v)
```

which is really only 1 additional line of code to provide the same API.  It's safer because you never know what someone did to mess with `Traits` to provide various descriptors (e.g. property) etc.  `setattr` will do all of that stuff correctly where blindly writing to `__dict__` could be potentially harmful.

Comment: You can, but you absolutely shouldn't.

Comment: @BenDundee: `for k, v in u.__dict__.items():`, for example. But I think keeping a traits dictionary is generally wiser.

Comment: @mgilson I wrote that when your post was just the first sentence. In trivial cases like your example (no other attributes), it's just an uglier way to use `getattr`/`setattr`, not actively harmful. But it sets a precedent for doing the same with other objects that might do "silly" things like providing any kind of descriptors, where using `__dict__` instead of `getattr`/`setattr` is plain wrong. You gain *nothing* by using `__dict__`, but potentially lose correctness.

Comment: @delnan -- You raise a valid point.  I'm willing to bet that you gain performance using `__dict__`.  Usually that's not a great reason to do something, but occasionally it is.