# Assigning multiple attributes to an object at once in Python

Tags: python, class, attributes, tuples

I have a function

```
def foo(a):
    first_thing = 'first' + a
    second_foo =  'second' + a + 'bar'
    return first_thing, second_foo
```

which returns tuples.
How can I achieve something like

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        first_thing, second_foo = foo(a)
        self.first_thing = first_thing
        self.second_foo = second_foo
```

in a nicer and more automated fashion?

I experimented with:

```
def __init__(self, a):
        for key, value in foo(a):
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

But can't unpack correctly.

Comment: `self.first_thing, self.second_foo = foo(a)`?

Comment: Are you returning an unknown number of arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.first_thing, self.second_foo = foo(a)
```

You do not need the first line inside `__init__()` function.

As per your comment, you can return a dictionary in your `foo` function and use `setattr()`, the updated solution would be:

```
def foo(a):
    first_thing = 'first' + a
    second_foo =  'second' + a + 'bar'
    return {'first_thing': first_thing, 'second_foo': second_foo}


class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        for k, v in foo(a).items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

Comment: But this means that I manually need to specify all the values. can't this be made a bit nicer i.e. something like java reflection which would take the literal name i.e. `first_thing` and store `first_thing`as an attribute and its respective value?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler in this case, you will need to return a dictionary instead of tuple in your `foo` function

Comment: Would you recommend `self.__dict__.update(foo(a))` or `setattr(self, k, v)`?

Comment: Personally I recommend `setattr()` as it's more safer. You can find some details in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504828/4575071

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns a tuple of values (a 2-tuple) not an iterable of 2-tuples. You're iterating over that tuple which contains strings, and you can't unpack those returned strings into twos.

You can stick with the original solution or unpack the items directly into the instance attributes:

```
self.first_thing, self.second_foo = foo(a)
```

And for many attributes:

```
_ATTR_NAMES = ('first_thing', 'second_foo')

class Thing(object)
    def __init__(self, a):
        for key, value in zip(_ATTR_NAMES, foo(a)):
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function returns a varying number of arguments, you could return a dictionary from `foo` instead, and update the `__dict__` attribute.

```
def foo(a):
    return {'first' : 'first' + a, 'second' : 'second' +  a + 'bar'}

class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__dict__.update(foo(a))
```

---

```
In [1233]: f = Thing('test')

In [1234]: f.first
Out[1234]: 'firsttest'

In [1235]: f.second
Out[1235]: 'secondtestbar'
```

Note the caveats with this approach, the most significant one being the lack of control over what is being updated.